# Input string was not in correct format while converting string to double

Tags: c#

I saw many posts related to this problem but non of the solutions worked for me.

```
string d = "";
d =reader.ReadLine();
filearr1[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(d);
```

in the above code I am reading lines from a file and converting them to double but it gives me this exception

> "input string was not in correct format".

Data inside the file is like this: one double value per line

```
0.0457707
0.0297815
-0.00791904
-0.0368762
-0.0171717
0.0367319
0.0148877
0.0464597
```

what can be the possible problem here? and the solution ?

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: So that is what is in the file.  What are you actually reading?  Put a Debug.WriteLine on D.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on your `Convert` line and when it breaks, check what's in the string `d`.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know what's that @SonerGönül

Comment: The problem is that you didn't use the debugger to step through your code. The solution is to use the debugger to step through your code.

Comment: As said above, I would check your input lines. The one showed in your question are all convertible to a double. At least, without knowing the value of CurrentCulture, they are convertible if you use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline the value of d is a string even after the Convert line

Comment: Try `Convert.ToDouble("-0.00791904", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: @JohnSaunders already tried didn't work :(

Comment: Are there spaces between the digits? I saw this one time when a file was UCS-2 encoded.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline no there are no spaces

Comment: Really, you tried a constant like that? Try `Convert.ToDouble("0.0", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Is it possible there are non-printable characters after the string, like maybe a null byte? On which line of the file is the conversion failing?

Comment: @JohnSaunders it works with the constant

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline on the first line

Comment: If it works with "0.0", then next try "-0.01". Or do you mean it worked with "-0.00791904"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders works with "-0.01" as well. tried with "0.0" first

Comment: So try "-0.00791904" now.

Comment: A question asked and not answered:  when the exception is thrown, what does the debugger tell you the value of `d` is?  I'd strongly suspect it's not one of those numbers.

Comment: @CharlesMager it is the number but in string like this "0.01744112"

Comment: And yet presumably `Convert.ToDouble("0.01744112")` works?  Something here isn't adding up.

Comment: exactly, now I am trying to analyze the whole file as it has around 80000 lines, I guess the file has some problem. I mean that's the only answer I can come up with

Comment: If you can upload the file (or part of the file that causes problems) somewhere and provide a small, complete example that would reproduce the issue then someone may be able to help.

Comment: sure first I will try it on my own if I couldn't solve it then I will surely upload the file, Thank You everyone for explaining everything to me.

Comment: Try this (only for diagnostic purposes: get rid of the extra code once you have the problem solved): `try {string d =reader.ReadLine();
filearr1[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(d);} catch (FormatException ex){Console.WriteLine("Bad format for [{0},{1}]: {2}\r\n{3}", i,j,d,ex); Console.ReadLine();}`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following instead of `Convert.ToDouble(d)`

```
Double.Parse(d, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Sorry, corrected. There should be your 'd' variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
Convert.ToDouble(d, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows you using variable `i` & `j`, but not how you are incrementing these.

I have used the following code to read doubles from a file and into an array.

```
var fileArray = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\inputs.txt");

var doubleArray = new double[fileArray.Length];

for (var i = 0; i < fileArray.Length; i++)
{
    doubleArray[i] = Convert.ToDouble(fileArray[i]);
}
```